# How to make the elements can read on the array?

Tags: php

I have this code

```
$query = "select * from user";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
$IDS=$row['id'];
$num=array($IDS);     
arsort($num);
foreach($num as $data){
    echo $data;
}
```

But later , the results are just as this 8 1 9 6 7 3 4 2 5. And if i change like this

```
$num=array(8, 1, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 5);     
arsort($num);
foreach($num as $data){
    echo $data;
}
```

So the result like this 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1. The results can be sorted from the biggest to the small. How to make $IDS can be read on an array ?

Comment: Try to remove `$num=array($IDS)` and do `$num=$row['id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this line to get data from table. No need to sort array.

```
$query = "select * from user order by id desc";
```